# How do I change the size of the font for the output of the Print[] command?

Tags: formatting, fonts, printing

I created a Stylesheet that increased the sizes of the fonts for the styles Input, Output and Text. Still, when I use the command Print[] the output comes out tiny.

In the code below I added some comments to the program trying to convey what is happening. The last line is not a Mathematica Output line, since the output of Print[] is Null. I omitted the line with that output. The last line is what is printed on the screen by Print[] (except for my comments).

How do I change the font size for the output of the Print[] command?

```
In[126]:= "Hello, World!" (* This text in big font *)

Out[126]= Hello, World! (* This text in big font *)

In[127]:= Print["Hello, World!"] (* This text in big font *)

Hello, World! (* This text in tiny font *)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify formatting directives for the `"Print"` style.  Adding this cell to the custom style sheet:

```
Cell[StyleData["Print"],
 FontSize->24,
 FontColor->RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]
```

Should produce:

[image]

There is also a `"MSG"` style for messages:

```
Cell[StyleData["MSG"],
 FontWeight->"Bold",
 FontColor->RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0]]
```

[image]

Both of these can be conveniently created by typing either `Print` or `MSG` (*without* quotation marks) into the **Enter a style name:** field of the Style Definitions editor, then using the standard formatting tools on the generated cells.