# Change Font and Size of Print[] output

Tags: output-formatting, stylesheet

I managed to create a definition for the "Print" style, following the instructions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66367/how-do-i-change-the-size-of-the-font-for-the-output-of-the-print-command). However, the result does not work in my v.12.1. On the plus side, a "Print" entry exists at the bottom of the list of styles to choose from /Format/Style but despite that, the output of the `Print[]` command appears as the highlighted "Print" style, it appears in the built-in font and size. In other words: I want the output of `Print[]` to be in the Georgia font, size 12. I edited the stylesheet (it now contains an entry `Cell[StyleData["Print"],...FontFamily->"Georgia",FontSize->12,...`). The output of `Print[]` continues not to be in Georgia 12 but the original font and size for it (Consolas 9).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After posing this question to Wolfram Technical Support and them huddling for quite a while, it turns out that code-like cells (input, output, print, and perhaps others) are subject to a slightly different regime. For them what needs to change is the option `StyleHints->{"CodeFont"->"Georgia"}` which I did by opening the stylesheet, selecting the Print style, searching the Options Inspector for StyleHints, and changing the values. What was there had one more option, which I had to delete. I like the Georgia font because each number looks different in shape and that works in formatted math output, like fractions and radicals, very nicely. Only the Euler constant's double-struck e and the double struck i of the imaginary unit do not look quite right. Many thanks to Victorique at Wolfram Tech Support!